# .back() in EJS using express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, onclick, window, ejs

i am attempting to use a `.back()` feature in this code:

```
<a onclick=<% this.window.history.back() %>
```

But i am getting history is undefined? but in the window theres a history... any suggestions on how to make this functional?

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution create js function wich redirect you, and don't use `this`

```html
<a class="go_back" />
```

```js
const goBackLink = document.querySelector(".go_back")
const historyGoBack = () => {
    window.history.back()
    goBackLink.removeEventListener("click", historyGoBack)
}
goBackLink.addEventListener("click", historyGoBack)
```